# Unable to create a workspace in Accurev

Tags: accurev

I am unable to create a workspace in Accurev. It's giving an error like this:

```
Workspace/ref tree location already in use. Its saying Error- 61 - client.c:569
```

Comment: What code are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That message usually means that the physical location where you are trying to place the workspace is already being used by another workspace. Even if it is a deactivated workspace you will not be able to use that location until you move the deactivated one. If this does not help I would suggest contacting accurev support (support.accurev.com or support@accurev.com)  for additional troubleshooting.